# Function to return the K closest points on a Cartesian plane results in "< not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'"

Tags: python

The distance from the origin (0, 0) to any point on a Cartesian plane is defined as:

```
import math
math.sqrt((x^2 + y^2))
```

I'm trying to write a function that returns the `K` closest points from the origin (0, 0).

For example:

```
Input:  [(1,1) ,(4,-2), (5,-2), (-2,0), (0,3), K=2]
Output:  (1,1), (-2,0)
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def closest_distances(points, K):
    distance_list = []
    for (x, y) in points:
        distance = (x^2 + y^2)**0.5
        distance_list.append(distance)
        sorted_distances = sorted(distance_list)
        closest = sorted_distances[0:K]
    return closest
```

I'm getting the following error when hitting `sorted_distances = sorted(distance_list)`:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Typo.  The exponentiation operator in Python is `**`, not `^`.  You're doing an "exclusive or`, so the values stay negative, and sqrt of a negative produces a complex value.

Comment: And, of course, you don't want to do the sort and closest extraction until the entire loop is complete.  So, un-indent those two lines.

Comment: And you do not to extract the square root  either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ending up with complex values in the distance list because you are using `(x^2 + y^2)` which uses the `^` operator but you should use the `**` operator for exponentiation. So:

```
def closest_distances(points, K):
    distance_list = []
    for (x, y) in points:
        distance = (x**2 + y**2)**0.5
        distance_list.append(distance)
        sorted_distances = sorted(distance_list)
    closest = sorted_distances[0:K]
    return closest
```